# How to display text Bold in Angular 8

Tags: angular

C#

```
  FormName = $"<b>{x.FormName}</b>  {Environment.NewLine + x.Path}"
```

Angular 8 HTML

```
  <div [innerText]="right.formName"></div>
```

It looks like this

[image]

But I want it to look like this , I want to make heading BOLD but I used above approach and its not working

**GIS Admin**

/user-management/gis-admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
<div [innerHTML]="right.formName"></div>
```

Is a property binding that will render HTML
AN example here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-innerhtml-binding-angular